# Log4j doesn't work

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I do not understand why my logger does not work only in this class

I did the same thing everywhere and it works very well you have an idea?

```
public class Agent {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(Agent.class);

        public method() {
            LOGGER.debug("test");
        }
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Did you try changing from .debug to .error to see if produces output? Where is the definition for the logger (the appenders, etc.)? Are you certain the method() is being called?

Comment: and what is your configuration of log4j ?

Comment: Like oliv37 and KevinO pointed out. Maybe your log level is not on DEBUG. Or do you write debug messages for all the classes, where you use Log4j?

Comment: try to set log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG in your log4j.xml

Comment: I just found thank you.
The properties file had set the logs of package INFO instead of DEBUG.